# Google Charts: tooltips have wrong position when inside a scrolling container

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts (the Timeline in particular) and I am facing a weird issue.

When the timeline is placed inside a container that can scroll vertically, the bars' tooltip's vertical position is wrong if the container is scrolled.

Basically, the more you scroll the more the tooltip "drifts down", I've taken some screenshot to illustrate this:

Here is the tooltip when the container is not scrolled, the position is correct:
[image]

Now, let's scroll a bit, the tooltip vertical position starts to drift:
[image]

...and the more we scroll, the more it drifts:
[image]

I've tried reproducing this in JSfiddle but with no success, unfortunately the original code is quite complex and difficult to replicate as a simple example, but any suggestion on how to even approach this is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, while waiting for answers I developed this workaround.

What we need to do is alter the `top` and `left` style properties of the tooltip, which fortunately for us has the `google-visualization-tooltip` class applied to it, so we can target it with CSS.

First of all, we put an empty style tag on our page that the code below will inject with the tooltip position:

```
<style id="tooltip-style"></style>
```

Note that we use a style tag instead of setting the required CSS properties directly because the tooltip element is constantly appearing and disappearing as the mouse moves.

Then, we hook into the chart's `ready` event (because we need the chart to be rendered for this code to work) and run the following code:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', (e) => {
    //This instruction selects the internal div that actually shows the scrollbar
    //The div is generated automatically by the Google library when you put the Timeline inside 
    //an element (#maincontainer in our case) that has a fixed height too small to fit the entire timeline
    //It unfortuantely has no classes to make a more specific selector
    let scrollElem = $(`#maincontainer > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div`);
    
    //We then monitor mouse movement on the scrollable div
    scrollElem.on('mousemove', function( event ) {
        //When mouse moves, we determine how much the container is scrolled vertically  
        let scrollAmnt = scrollElem.scrollTop();
        
        //then we update a CSS style tag that forces the tooltip to a specific position
        //Y-axis position = level with mouse pointer (= mouse Y-position relative to scrolling container - scroll amount)
        //X-axis position = just to the right of the mouse pointer
        $('#tooltip-style').text(`.google-visualization-tooltip{
            top: ${event.offsetY - scrollAmnt}px !important; 
            left: ${event.offsetX + 15}px !important;
        }`);
    });
});
```

maybe not the prettiest of solutions, but works great.

Comment: Hey - just found this solution it is great!  Solves the scrolling issue and positions it better anyway, right next to the mouse cursor.  Only adjustment I would see, if the timeline chart goes all the way to the right side of the window, then the tooltip will go offscreen when you're on the right edge of the screen.  As a workaround, I adjusted the position leftward about 200px so it shows always on left instead of right, since I have a left sidebar space available.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show in an example how to use the above code? A typical Google Charts code has `dataTable.addRows` and `var options`. I pased the above code in between these two but it didn't work for me. So a full working example will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Inspired_Blue: I've edited the answer because there were a couple of important things left out. Notice in particular that the code runs after the chart is ready, and the fact that you need to add a style tag with a specific ID to the page. Also notice that I've not used this code in 3+ years, so I can't guarantee that it still works, Google might have modified its charting library since then and the HTML structure inside it might be different, so you'll need to test it.